# Does the order of headers in an HTTP response ever matter?

Tags: http-headers

Is it ever meaningful whether the order of headers is

```
A: 1
B: 2
```

vs

```
B:2
A:1
```

I'm trying to figure out if I can use a dictionary to store a list of headers or if it needs to be some kind of list or ordered dictionary.

Comment: The order of the "request" headers can be used for browsers/bots fingerprinting.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

No, it does not matter for headers with different names.  See [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), section 4.2:

> The order in which header fields with differing field names are
> received is not significant. However, it is "good practice" to send
> general-header fields first, followed by request-header or response-
> header fields, and ending with the entity-header fields.

It DOES matter, however, for multiple headers with the same name:

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be
> present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that
> header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)].
> It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one
> "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the
> message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each
> separated by a comma. The order in which header fields with the same
> field-name are received is therefore significant to the
> interpretation of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT
> change the order of these field values when a message is forwarded.

Comment: ASP.net uses a plain NameValueCollection to store the response headers.

Comment: For multiple headers with the same name it matters EVEN MORE if its not legal for that header to appear multiple times, e.g. `Content-Length` - different servers will handle it in a different way. E.g. one will take the first, one will take the last, and another will be randomly undefined. So while it makes a difference, there might not be much you can do about it.

Comment: (Oh dang, just noticed the date you posted this...! :-O Sorry, I just happened across it now...)

Comment: @AviD: Yes, that's where the "if and only if the entire field-value for that header field is defined as a comma-separated list" condition kicks in.  Headers like Content-Length are NOT a comma-separate list, so multiple Content-Length headers are not allowed.  But the Accept header is a comma-separated list, so having multiple headers like "Accept: text/plain" and "Accept: text/html" is equivalent to "Accept: text/plain, text/html", but NOT equivalent to "Accept: text/html, text/plain" (the order matters).

Comment: RFC 2616 has been obsoleted by RFC 7230, but the rules stay the same, as mentioned in [section 3.2.2. *Field Order*](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.2).

Answer (score 9):

The order of the headers should not matter.  There might be "weaker" implementations of HTTP standard where the ordering does matter, but it shouldn't in general.

Here's a link that describes HTTP headers:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2

Answer (score 3):

HTTP Headers are independent of each other and you can use a dictionary to store them without worrying about their order.

Comment: Not true for multiple occurances of the same header.

Answer (score 2):

It could also matter when specifying `set-cookie` several times for the same cookie:

```
"Set-Cookie: COOKIE1=VALUE1; ...
"Set-Cookie: COOKIE1=VALUE2; ...
```

In this case, `COOKIE1` will be set to `VALUE2`, and if the order is changed:

```
"Set-Cookie: COOKIE1=VALUE2; ...
"Set-Cookie: COOKIE1=VALUE1; ...
```

`COOKIE1` will be set to `VALUE1`

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 7230, section 3.2.2: Field Order](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.2) addresses this question specifically. Quotes here are from that section of the specification, with emphasis added by me:

> The order in which header fields **with differing field names** are received is **not significant**.

It goes on to qualify that with a note about good practice for the sake of performance:

> However, it is good practice to send header fields that contain control data first, such as Host on requests and Date on responses, so that implementations can decide when not to handle a message as early as possible.

In certain cases it is permissible for a message to contain multiple header fields with the same name. In this case, order does matter.

> A recipient MAY combine multiple header fields with the same field name into one "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the message, by appending each subsequent field value to the combined field value in order, separated by a comma.  The order in which header fields **with the same field name** are received is therefore **significant** to the interpretation of the combined field value.

Comment: My answer here is not significantly different from existing ones, but I wanted to add a new updated answer that quotes the current HTTP/1.1 spec instead of the outdated RFC 2616.