# Is the order of webrequest Headers important?

Tags: http-post, httpwebrequest, http-request, http-error

I'm making a POST request to upload a picture to a website.
In the page, there is one `FileUpload` and one `input` `(textBox)` and in fiddler I found out that the page is sending some data using Multipart Post request mode `(Content Disposition: multipart-formdata;)`
Everything seems to be OK, coz in fiddler everything is the same about what my app is posting and what the page is sending...  Just not about headers order...

My question is that is it really important to put headers in a right order? and if yes, how can I do it? (as we are just setting some properties in request, there is no where to set the order...)

thanks for any advise...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the order of headers in an HTTP response ever matter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750330/does-the-order-of-headers-in-an-http-response-ever-matter)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order of HTTP Headers doesn't matter for headers with different names.  If there are multiple headers with the same name, however, the order is important.

See [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2)

> **The order in which header fields with differing field names are
> received is not significant**. However, it is "good practice" to send
> general-header fields first, followed by request-header or response-
> header fields, and ending with the entity-header fields.

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be
> present in a message if and only if the entire field-value for that
> header field is defined as a comma-separated list [i.e., #(values)].
> It MUST be possible to combine the multiple header fields into one
> "field-name: field-value" pair, without changing the semantics of the
> message, by appending each subsequent field-value to the first, each
> separated by a comma. **The order in which header fields with the same
> field-name are received is therefore significant** to the
> interpretation of the combined field value, and thus a proxy MUST NOT
> change the order of these field values when a message is forwarded.

Comment: No idea.  You haven't provided enough information to answer that question.  Is an exception being thrown on the server?

Comment: I have no access to the server... the only thing i guess is about encoding of string values... Does it really make this error appear to me?

Comment: I would contact the administrator of the server for help troubleshooting then.  Without knowing what error is causing the HTTP 500, you're going to be running in circles.

Answer (score 6):

Akamai *will* block you if you have the wrong order.

```
$ curl -v -H "$UA" -H "$ACCEPT" -H "$ENCODING" $URL |& grep '< HTTP'
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
$ curl -v -H "$ACCEPT" -H "$UA" -H "$ENCODING" $URL |& grep '< HTTP'
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
```

They use the implicit ordering of specific clients to detect malicious user agents. See my blog the topic:

http://gwillem.gitlab.io/2017/05/02/http-header-order-is-important/

Comment: I had the same issue, Akamai takes into consideration the order of the headers (not just the order as you explain in your post)

Answer (score 1):

I my experience with Chrome's webRequest api, there is never any guaranteed order of http headers. So, on that front, header order doesn't matter.