# mochiweb: disable headers ordering

Tags: erlang, mochiweb

I checked mochiweb response headers, and they are always ordered (descending):

```
< Server: MochiWeb/1.0 (Any of you quaids got a smint?)
< last-modified: Sun, 30 Aug 2015 23:13:04 GMT
< Date: Sun, 30 Aug 2015 23:15:15 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 89
```

This looks to be because of mochiweb headers are being handled with an erlang `gb_tree`, which is later converted to a list so it comes ordered.

Is there a way to change this? as this could resolve in problems (sometimes) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750330/does-the-order-of-headers-in-an-http-response-ever-matter/32281445#32281445) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197693/is-the-order-of-webrequest-headers-important)

My problem is that I am trying to create a service that replicates some requests and I am using mochiweb for this, but Headers are being ordered so it isn't completely replicating the response correctly.

Comment: Short of replacing the implementation in [mochiweb_headers.erl](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/mochiweb_headers.erl) with a different approach, I don't think there's any good way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed here:

[mochiweb commit 952087e](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/commit/952087ef7a2ce73b8c2d666de13adf138d913d77)

It was a problem with formatting the headers in the response, and not in `mochiweb_headers`.