# Different results between requests.get and aiohttp GET and Httpx module

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp, httpx

I am trying to access a site with a bot prevention.

with the following script using requests I can access the site.

```py
request = requests.get(url,headers={**HEADERS,'Cookie': cookies})
```

and I am getting the desired HTML. but when I use aiohttp

```py
async def get_data(session: aiohttp.ClientSession,url,cookies):
    async with session.get(url,timeout = 5,headers={**HEADERS,'Cookie': cookies}) as response:
        text = await response.text()
        print(text)
```

I am getting as a response the bot prevention page.

This is the headers I use for all the requests.

```py
HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.29.0',
    'Host': 'www.dnb.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': '/',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
}
```

I have compared the requests headers both of requests.get and aiohttp and they are identical.

is there any reason the results are different? if so why?

EDIT: I've checked the httpx module, the problem occurs there aswell both with `httpx.Client()` and `httpx.AsyncClient()`.

```py
response = httpx.request('GET',url,headers={**HEADERS,'Cookie':cookies})
```

doesn't work as well. (not asyncornic)

Answer (score 1):

I tried capturing packets with wireshark to compare requests and aiohttp.

Server:

```python
    import http
    server = http.server.HTTPServer(("localhost", 8080), 
    http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

with requests:

```python
    import requests
    url = 'http://localhost:8080'
    HEADERS = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    cookies = ''
    request = requests.get(url,headers={**HEADERS,'Cookie': cookies})
```

requests packet:

```html
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:8080
    User-Agent: python-requests/2.27.1
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept: */*
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Type: application/json
    Cookie:
```

with aiohttp:

```python
    import aiohttp
    import asyncio
    
    url = 'http://localhost:8080'
    HEADERS = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    cookies = ''
    async def get_data(session: aiohttp.ClientSession,url,cookies):
        async with session.get(url,timeout = 5,headers={**HEADERS,'Cookie': cookies}) as response:
            text = await response.text()
            print(text)
    
    async def main():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            await get_data(session,url,cookies)
    
    asyncio.run(main())
```

aiohttp packet:

```html
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:8080
    Content-Type: application/json
    Cookie: 
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    User-Agent: Python/3.10 aiohttp/3.8.1
```

If the site seems to accept packets from requests, then you could try making the aiohttp packet identical by setting the headers:

```python
    HEADERS = { 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.27.1','Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Cookie': ''}
```

If you haven't already, I suggest capturing the request with wireshark to make sure aiohttp isn't messing with your headers.

You can also try other user agent strings too, or try the headers in different orders. The order is not supposed to matter, but some sites check it anyway for bot protection (for example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63616473/strict-ordering-of-http-headers-in-httpwebrequest)).

Comment: Hey, I've tried capturing the request in wireshark but its encrypted via TLSv1.3 so I cant decrypt it.
I've also had the same headers set for both requests
```HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.29.0',
    'Host': 'www.dnb.com',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': '/',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
}
```