# Strict ordering of HTTP headers in POST HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm using this example and can't move "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" to end headers

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "www.google.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 etc");
            await client.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");
            await client.PostAsync("http://www.google.com", new StringContent(""));
        }
    }
}
```

I read topic [Strict ordering of HTTP headers in HttpWebrequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63616473/strict-ordering-of-http-headers-in-httpwebrequest) and didn't find answer

I have:

```
POST /v3/sessions HTTP/2
Host: www.google.com
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 129

{"authToken":"d81932c781288890e2348e622b45b27627696e818d03bdc8c6cc60bb6be1fa43","thirdPartyUserId":"google"}
```

I need:

```
   POST /v3/sessions HTTP/2
    Host: www.google.com
    Accept-Language: en-US
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 129
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    
    {"authToken":"d81932c781288890e2348e622b45b27627696e818d03bdc8c6cc60bb6be1fa43","thirdPartyUserId":"google"}
```

upd.
I did it with curl requests

Comment: I'd love to know which broken web server you are calling that depends on the order of the headers.

Comment: Potential [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @Charlieface cloudflare

Comment: I find that difficult to believe, Cloudflare is big enough to be not broken like that. Please tell us what you are doing with it that would require such a thing. Firewall rule? Proxy?