# Does it matter in which order the cache headers are sent?

Tags: php, http

Various sources mention different way to control cache using headers:

```
Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT'

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate

Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

What I'm wondering is: what is the priority order of these headers? Say I set "Exprires" to 1 day from now, what would happen to the other headers? Do they override the Exprires header?

Also does it matter in which order these headers are sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Cache-Control" takes precedence over "Expires." (Source: http://www.kaizou.org/2009/02/http-caching-explained/)

HTTP header order is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750330/does-the-order-of-headers-in-an-http-response-ever-matter). The "Expires" and "Cache-Control" headers can appear in either order, and the two "Cache-Control" values might just as well be merged into a single header:

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```