# How can I change order of HTTP headers sent by Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

I see that I can change what headers will be sent by modifying request.headers from a middleware, but can I change their order? I cannot do with the default implementation of the request.headers since it is based on an unordered dictionary.

Comment: What's the goal though?

Comment: please check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/750338/858913) as it explains order really doesn't matter for requests, unless you are sending multiple headers with the same name, is that the case?

Comment: Thanks. This is needed to bypass one of the techniques for bot detection via browser fingerprinting when the order of HTTP headers is used to identify the requester.

Comment: Any update on this?