# swagger 2 UI, ordering of received headers

Tags: swagger-2.0

The swagger 2 GUI Response Headers view does not seem to display the received headers in the order they appear on thw wire, but instead in a random order.

I have a number of headers (added by jersey) of the form *X-Jersey-Tracing-00x,* these appear on the wire in sequence

curl -v gives  me the headers in the correct order.

Is this a know bug ?

Answer (score 1):

[There is no defined order for HTTP Response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750338/3990817), except for the status line (which should always be first). So the term 'correct order' is inapplicable to headers in this particular case. I guess that since Swagger first puts the header lines in a JS object, does a little bit of processing and only then lists them, the ordering might be different than `cURL`'s.

If I had to guess, I'd say they won't make Swagger compatible to cURL's output, as the order is not important in the first place.

Comment: Well, the order is important when debugging.

I was a bit unclear, I know ordering is not defined, but lexiographic order in the UI would be useful.

I now get this, which is hard to read.
{
   "x-jersey-tracing-014": INVOKE... 
   "x-jersey-tracing-007": REQ-FILTER...
   "x-jersey-tracing-001": "PRE-MATCH... 
 }